# PHP If and Else operating incorrectly

Tags: php, if-statement

The following PHP should determine if there `?purpose=email` and then if it is determine the sting contains `?emailaddress` or not. If there is an emailaddress then it triggers one set of scripts and if not another. But regardless it is acting as if `emailaddress !== '';` Any idea why.

```
<?php if($_GET['purpose'] == 'email') {?>
<?php   if($_GET['emailaddress'] !== '') {?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    alert('<?php echo $_GET['emailaddress'];?>');
    window.setTimeout(function(){
      $('.dirops .loadpanel div span', window.parent.document).html('Complete');
      $('.dirops .loadpanel', window.parent.document).removeClass('slideup');
    },1000);
  </script>
<?php } else { ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.setTimeout(function(){
      $('.dirops .loadpanel div span', window.parent.document).html('Loading');
      $('.dirops .confirmemail', window.parent.document).addClass('slideup');
    },1000);
    $('#confirmemail', window.parent.document).attr('href', 'http://www.golfbrowser.com/A4/directions.php?purpose=email&start=<?php echo $_GET['start'];?>&end=<?php echo $_GET['end'];?>')
  </script>
<?php   } ?> 
<?php } ?>
```

Any ideas?

Marvellous

Comment: This is example code, right? you wouldn't directly print a query-string variable into the page without escaping, right? "`echo $_GET['emailaddress'];`" --shudder--

Comment: What url are you using to access the script?

Comment: `$_GET['emailaddress']` might contain, for example, `'<script type="text/javascript">(arbitrary JavaScript)</script>'`

Comment: @RobinKnight The danger comes from me sending you a link to `?purpose=email&emailaddress=Hi')%3B%20alert('This%202nd%20alert%20is%20a%20XSS%20attack.` or something like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `if($_GET['emailaddress'] != '')`, i.e. `!=` instead of `!==`

Comment: To clarify: when emailaddress is missing, it's probably set to `null`, and `null !== ''`, causing your "success" condition to run.

Comment: better to use `if ( empty( $_GET['emailaddress'] ) )`

Answer (score 3):

Use: `array_key_exists('emailaddress', $_GET)` instead of `$_GET['emailaddress'] !== ''`

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isset($_GET['emailaddress'])) { ....
```

Comment: +1. I imagine his `if` is failing because he's using type comparison as well, and if the GET parameters is absent, the array value is `null`, and `null !== ''` is `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow I don't think that if/else is not working...

try `var_dump($_GET)` maybe `isset($_GET['emailaddress'])` can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this changing the first two lines:

```
<?php if(array_key_exists('purpose', $_GET) && $_GET['purpose'] == 'email') {?>
<?php   if(array_key_exsist('emailaddress', $_GET) && $_GET['emailaddress'] != '') {?>
```